# Sorting structure with C qsort()

Tags: c, sorting, struct, qsort

Having trouble getting my head around implementing the qsort() built into C to sort an array of structs by a stored int value (hitCount).

My struct:

```
typedef struct words {
    const char *word;
    int hitCount;
} words;
```

I'm trying to use the example given by Microsoft (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/73853).

So I've got at the top:

```
typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);
```

and the comparision method:

```
int compare (words *a, words *b) {
    if (a->hitCount > b->hitCount) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a->hitCount < b->hitCount) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then within another method I call qsort with my array name and other details replacing the Microsoft example:

```
qsort((void *) &output, outputLength, sizeof(words), (compfn)compare);
```

This gives a segmentation fault.

I don't fully understand how to use qsort so I assume where I've adapted it from Microsoft's example I've done it incorrectly.

I hope I've included the mistake and can get some enlightenment as to what I should be doing in order for this to work correctly.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is output? Show the part of the code calling the fucntion

Comment: Full method containing qsort: http://pastebin.com/y6ziACWy

Comment: What is `outputLength`? Where is the definition of `output`?

Comment: Dont't do any explicit cast unless you both know what it does and it is really needed. Let the compiler warn you, no muzzling it. Also, always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: What should I be doing instead?

Comment: first, cast to `void*` is not needed, remove it. Second, use the proper prototype, never try to force the compiler to pretend. You'll get bitten when you least expect it, and bug searching gets really hard.

Comment: @Matt: Please do not use any external code. Instead, give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is better all around. Especially when you hide that link in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the array not the address of the array to qsort.

```
qsort( output, ... );
```

Also your compare function *must* return an int and accept two const void* arguments.
Casting your function `int compare (words *a, words *b)` to a different( yet correct ) type which is then called by qsort() will cause undefined behaviour.

The compare function must be:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)...
```

Then you cast a and b to correct types:

```
((words*)a)->hitCount < ((words*)b)->hitCount
```

Comment: The address of the array is the address of the first element of the array, so no harm done!

Comment: @Deduplicator &output is the address of the pointer, not the address of the array.

Comment: `char array[2];assert((void*)array == (void*)&array);`

Comment: @Deduplicator That is true, yet completely useless information. Passing an incorrect type is wrong.

Comment: @Pete: That is the first i hear about output being a pointer and not an array.

Comment: @self: It's passing the right pointer, having the right type, just after unneccessarily jumping through a few more hoops.

Comment: @Deduplicator Show me where the standard guarantees that the address of the array is the same as the array? The next time it isn't the code will break. Such assumptions like yours cause the code to break years later.

Comment: The standard guarantees that using an array in a pointer context makes it implicitly decay to a pointer to the first element. Also, it guarantees that the first element of a structure / union / array is at the start of its space, without any padding. So, they are the same after void* conversion.

Comment: @Deduplicator Dynamically allocate your array and see how it works. In C/C++ array=pointer. Thus, if you heard it was an array, you heard it was a pointer.

Comment: @Pete: You are so wrong. You can assign to a pointer, try that with an array. In C, array decays to const pointer everywhere but in a few special places.

Comment: I've updated to "self's" recommendations (http://pastebin.com/k0rLnf30) and I'm getting 4 errors of the same kind but pointing to different sections `error: member reference base type 'const void' is not a
      structure or union
        if ((words *)a->hitCount > (words *)b->hitCount) {`

Comment: Assume `char * p = malloc(10);` then `&p != p` is true. @Deduplicator

Comment: @Deduplicator As I said, take your little example above, dynamically allocate array and see if your assert works.

Comment: well, then we have a pointer, not an array. Those have different behavior, also for `&`. As i said. So what is your contention?

Comment: My contention is that he can't pass &output to `qsort` because output is a pointer.

Comment: So, you finally concede array is not a pointer, though you still did not point out where it said pointer. BTW: I found it in the linked paste.

Comment: @Deduplicator Pete Would you two please use chat and not my answer to resolve your problems. Grrr...

Comment: Tried the above and I'm getting: `member reference base type 'const void' is not a structure or union`

Comment: You are casting incorrectly. Take a good look at the parenthesis. Alternatively you have a complete solution below.

Comment: @Matt: Where is your updated code? Looks like you forgot some stars or casts.

Comment: I've corrected the paranthesis and it compiles successfully but I'm back to a segmentation fault like when I use the example bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that outputLength is computed incorrectly.  A complete working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct words {
    const char *word;
    int hitCount;
} words;

int compare(const void * left, const void * right) {
    const words * a = (const words *) left;
    const words * b = (const words *) right;
    if (a->hitCount > b->hitCount) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a->hitCount < b->hitCount) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct words output[] = {
      { "hello", 314 },
      { "world", 42 },
      { "answer", 42 }
    };
    int outputLength = sizeof(output) / sizeof(output[0]);
    int i;

    output[0].word = "hello";
    output[0].hitCount = 314;
    output[1].word = "world";
    output[1].hitCount = 42;
    qsort(output, outputLength, sizeof(words), compare);

    for (i = 0; i < outputLength; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s\n", output[i].hitCount, output[i].word);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what I'm doing I create an array from a hash table. So the length of the array is the same as the amount structs in the hash table that aren't still set as empty. I've made the changes you've suggested an still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Then I suspect the bug is in how you initialize the array from the hash table.  It's probably time to learn how to use a debugger.  http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Was nothing to do with the array. Was conditions external to the method causing issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of the standard library function `qsort` is

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Note the signature of the `compare` function. **You cannot typecast a pointer to a function of different signature and make it work correctly.** Therefore, typecasting your compare function will not work. It must have the same signature as declared in the prototype of `qsort`. Change your `compare` function to -

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int c = ((words *) a)->hitCount;
    int d = ((words *) b)->hitCount;

    if(c > d) return -1;
    if(c < d) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

The first argument `base` of `qsort` is the base address of the buffer which contains the elements to be sorted. Also, any pointer type is assignment compatible to a `void *` variable and as such you don't need to cast the base address. Therefore, you should call the `qsort` function as -

```
qsort(output, outputLength, sizeof output[0], compare);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
    int compare (const void *a, const void *b) {
        if (((words *)a)->hitCount > ((words *)b)->hitCount) {
            return -1;
        } else if (((words *)a)->hitCount < ((words *)b)->hitCount) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

and call to sort:

```
    qsort(output, outputLength, sizeof(words), compare);
```

Thanks to everyone's help but majority credit to "self".

Comment: The correction of `&output` to `output` was only discernible by OP as OP did not post the declaration of `output`.

Comment: I like the subtraction simplification, instead of a bunch of compares.  Return the difference of dereferenced p and q.  In my case I just came up with: return ((struct filerec *)p)->fsize - ((struct filerec *)q)->fsize;  But it didn't work until I added the parens around (struct filerec *)q and p.